# WTForms - Is there an object field?

Tags: flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am trying to make a form that submits an object, ex:

```py
class SignUpForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('username', validators=[DataRequired()]
    password = PasswordField('password', validators=[DataRequired()]
```

How do I make it so I can put this data in my Mongo database as an object? I want it to be put in like this:

```
"credentials": {
    "username": username,
    "password": password
}
```

I haven't found any documentation for anything related to object fields.

Answer (score 0):

It creates a form object, so you can just translate that into whatever format you want afterwards:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    data = {
        "credentials": {
            "username": form.username.data,
            "password" form.password.data
        }
    }

    insert_into_your_database(data)
```